# Grouping countries in Highmaps

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, highmaps

I am using highmaps to display data segmented by countries. It works nice but I have an issue I'm not sure how to approach.

I need to group some countries of Central America and Venezuela together in the world-map and show them as one single country. This grouping could change in time so it would be nice to be able to do it programmatically. I tried passing an array in the joinBy field of that concrete point but it does not work and neither the documentation or examples mention anything about what I'm trying to accomplish.

How would you guys do it?

Comment: Do you consider using [categories](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/category-map) like here?

Comment: I would need the category to behave like a single country itself. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok, so only way is use a source of data which contains all grouped countries as single path / shape.

Comment: I finally did it as you suggested Sebastian, it would be nice to be able to group regions as a feature for future versions tho.
Thank you for your help!